# Finding 4 highest values from an array

Tags: php, arrays, max

Instead of just 1, how can I pick the 4 highest values from an array using `max()`?

Comment: you cant with `max`. [`max()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) *returns the numerically highest of the parameter values. If multiple values can be considered of the same size, the one that is listed first will be returned.*

Comment: As Gordon said, you can't do that. However you can be clever and once you find the max value - remove it from array and run max() again repeating the process until you're satisfied.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will do it in Θ(n) time:

```
$a = $b = $c = $d = null;
foreach($array as $v) {
  if(!isset($a) || $v > $a) {
    $d = $c;
    $c = $b;
    $b = $a;
    $a = $v;
  }elseif(!isset($b) || $v > $b) {
    $d = $c;
    $c = $b;
    $b = $v;
  }elseif(!isset($c) || $v > $c) {
    $d = $c;
    $c = $v;
  }elseif(!isset($d) || $v > $d) {
    $d = $v;
  }
}

$result = array($a, $b, $c, $d);
```

Comment: That's really interesting, I've just done a quick'n'durty benchmark (https://gist.github.com/973159) and this is indeed faster, although it seems only to be faster when there is a huge number of elements in the array.  I guess the fact that the `asort` solution is implemented in PHP (at a lower level) also has a bearing.

Comment: Robin, you are probably correct. Asymptotic runtimes are not especially important for small problem sizes.

Comment: @Robin it isnt faster on my machine. I've tried your benchmark multiple times now and the `array_slice` variant outperformed this after each subsequent run after the first run. Also see http://codepad.viper-7.com/5yMTuu

Comment: @Gordon - Note there's a bug in my Gist code (and in your Viper code) the function '`fixed` should say `return array($a,$b,$c,$d);` not `return array_slice($array, -4);`.  This may have a bearing on the results.  Also, in my tests the `fixed` function was slower on arrays smaller than 100,000 items.

Comment: @Robin Ah, I see. Yes. See fixed version: http://codepad.viper-7.com/XN1w8Z and version with more than 100k elements: http://codepad.viper-7.com/hXeTxl. This again teaches us that benchmarks are utterly useless without context :)

Answer (score 10):

You could use an [`SplMaxHeap`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splmaxheap.php)

```
function maxN(array $numbers, $n)
{
    $maxHeap = new SplMaxHeap;
    foreach($numbers as $number) {
        $maxHeap->insert($number);
    }
    return iterator_to_array(
        new LimitIterator($maxHeap, 0, $n)
    );
}
```

Usage ([demo](http://eval.in/16381)):

```
print_r( maxN( array(7,54,2,4,26,7,82,4,34), 4 ) );
```

Comment: +1 for a simple, clean usage of Iterators and SPL data structures to solve the problem!

Answer (score 7):

You could try this:

```
$a = array(3,5,6,1,23,6,78,99);
asort($a);
var_dump(array_slice($a, -4));
```

HTH.

Comment: Only downside of this method: Its runtime is in `O(n log n)` and not `O(n)` as it should be.

Comment: @phihag - that's very interesting - what would an `O(n+4)` solution look like?

Comment: @Robin Sorry, it's not actually `O(n+4)`, but `O(4n)` (or just `O(n)`). I added an academic answer, but Emil's is better.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but what's with the O(n) and O(n log n) stuff? And how come Emil's answer is really different from the others?

Comment: Kemal, we are talking about runtime complexity. If you increase a problem size, how much do the time to solve it increase? Consider that you have an algorithm which solves something in O(n^2). This means that if you double the problem size, you quadruple the runtime. An algorithm of O(n) will instead increase in the same pace as the problem size, e.g., doubling the size will take double the time. This may matter a lot if the problem is large.

Comment: Calculating runtime complexity is teached early on in all computer science classes at universities. If you are interested, I recommend picking up a book on algorithms (for example this one: http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Algorithms-Second-Thomas-Cormen/dp/0262032937 )

Answer (score 2):

```
function maxs($ar, $count=4) 
{
    $res = array();

    foreach ($ar as $v) 
    {
        for ($i = 0;$i < $count;$i++) 
        {
            if ($i >= count($res) || $v > $res[$i]) 
            {
                do 
                {
                    $tmp = $res[$i];
                    $res[$i] = $v;
                    $v = $tmp;
                    $i++;
                } 
                while ($i < $count);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $res;
}
```

Comment: ... except that rsort will run in O(n log n), or do you have a way to show that it in this special case will perform better?

Comment: Oh, maybe you are right after all. $res will be a small array, so the nlogn of rsort can be considered a constant (I guess).

Comment: @Emil Vikström Exactly, rsort will run in O(4 log 4). For large values of 4, one would have to have a helper insertion function that would be longer than 2 lines.

Comment: @Emil Vikström Updated to a solution in `Θ(4n)` instead of `O(4n log(4))` that generalizes your solution (but looks way uglier ;) ).

Comment: Nice. Your solution should perform just as well as mine now. But I think you should drop the `4` in your asymptotic runtime complexity - you've already dropped all other constants anyway, so why bother keeping one of them? ;-)

Comment: Or wait, your solution doesn't perform just as well as my solution after all, since your condition check is done for all elements in $res, which mine doesn't. But at least they scale just as well, and the difference is mostly theoretical anyway.

Comment: @Emil Vikström I kept the 4 intentionally, as a shorthand for `$count`. Using numbers as symbols in asymptotic complexities might be a local convention I picked up, though. By the way, a personal note: Your homepage is awesome! I sure hope the list "Currently teached by" doesn't include English teachers ;) Greetings from (HHU) Düsseldorf!

Comment: Is my English that bad? :-( I think your page is cleaner than mine, which may be a good thing.

Comment: @Emil Vikström Not at all, it's way better than mine - you seem to use *teached* instead of the proper form *taught* sometimes. Sorry, I shouldn't have brought it up, throwing rocks while being in fragile houses and all. By the way, looping through `$res` is what you do too, if all if/elseif conditions have to be evaluated. In the general case, one could traverse `$res` from either side, and there are worst case scenarios that turn it into `O(4n log 4)` either way.

Comment: @Emil Vikström Sorry, sometimes what I say or write comes out as insufferably smug. Please rest assured that I wanted to convey only the nicest of wishes and would love to cross paths with you in a Debian or computer science setting.

Comment: No hard feelings, I didn't get sad for real. On the contrary, I value and appreciate honesty!

Answer (score 1):

A simple method using php predefined functions.

```
<?php
  $arr = array(6, 8, 3, 2, 7, 9);

  rsort($arr);

  $first = array_shift($arr);
  $second = array_shift($arr);
  $third = array_shift($arr);

  echo $first; // print 9
  echo $second; // print 8
  echo $third; // print 7
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

While storing itself you can maintain another array as soon as the new item is inserted check with the max value in the inner array if the item being inserted is greater insert this item. During the item pop do viceversa. From the inner maintained array you can get as many max numbers as possible.