# Python: Getting the top 4 Highest Values in a 2d List

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-3.x, 2d

Okay this may be similar to this thread: [Finding 4 highest values from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008440/finding-4-highest-values-from-an-array)

But I don't know how to do it with 2d lists so this is my problem:
I have a list:

```
teams = [Randomteam1,Randomteam2,Randomteam3,Randomteam4,Randomteam5,Randomteam6]
```

and a 2d list:

```
team_info = [[7, 2, 1, 1, 3], [4, 1, 1, 1, 3],[2, 0, 2, 2, 3], [12, 3, 0, 0, 3]],
             [9, 0, 2, 2, 3], [10, 3, 0, 0, 6]]
```

In that list each for example, [7, 2, 1, 1, 3] is an information of a teams scores, 7 is how many points, 2 how many wins, 1 loses, 1 draws, 3 is for games played. And each block in team_info is connected to 1 of the teams in teams. For example:

```
Randomteam1 = [7, 2, 1, 1, 3], Randomteam2 = [4, 1, 1, 1, 3]
```

and so on..

Now I want to get/display the top 4 teams with the most POINTS, and the bottom 2 teams with the lowest points.

Comment: So you want `sorted(team_info)[:2]` and `sorted(team_info)[-2:]`?

Comment: I wanted the top for which is `sorted(team_info)[:4]` and bottom 2 `sorted(team_info)[-2:]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would  probably have used a dict but you can zip the lists together to make pairs then sort:

```
teams = ["Randomteam1","Randomteam2","Randomteam3","Randomteam4","Randomteam5","Randomteam6"]


team_info = [[7, 2, 1, 1, 3], [4, 1, 1, 1, 3],[2, 0, 2, 2, 3], [12, 3, 0, 0, 3], [9, 0, 2, 2, 3], [10, 3, 0, 0, 6]]


data = sorted(zip(teams,team_info),key= lambda x: x[1][0],reverse=True)

[('Randomteam4', [12, 3, 0, 0, 3]), ('Randomteam6', [10, 3, 0, 0, 6]), ('Randomteam5', [9, 0, 2, 2, 3]), ('Randomteam1', [7, 2, 1, 1, 3]), ('Randomteam2', [4, 1, 1, 1, 3]), ('Randomteam3', [2, 0, 2, 2, 3])]
```

The  result is the teams are sorted in order of highest score to lowest, the sort key is `x[1][0]` which is the first element of the second element in each pairing which is each teams total points.

top 4 will be `data[:4]`, the  last two teams will be `data[-2:]`

If you use a dict it will be easy to associate the teams and to access any 
of their data, you can store the team and data as a dict and use a rank as the key:

```
data = {}
srt = sorted(zip(team_info, teams), reverse=True,1)
for ind, (b,a) in enumerate(srt):
    p, w, l, d, gp = b
    data["rank_{}".format(ind)] = {"team":a,"points": p, "wins": w, "loss": l, "draw": d, "games": gp}



from pprint import pprint as pp

pp(data)
```

Output:

```
{'rank_1': {'team': 'Randomteam4',
            'draw': 0,
            'games': 3,
            'loss': 0,
            'points': 12,
            'wins': 3},
 'rank_2': {'team': 'Randomteam6',
            'draw': 0,
            'games': 6,
            'loss': 0,
            'points': 10,
            'wins': 3},
 'rank_3': {'team': 'Randomteam5',
            'draw': 2,
            'games': 3,
            'loss': 2,
            'points': 9,
            'wins': 0},
 'rank_4': {'team': 'Randomteam1',
            'draw': 1,
            'games': 3,
            'loss': 1,
            'points': 7,
            'wins': 2},
 'rank_5': {'team': 'Randomteam2',
            'draw': 1,
            'games': 3,
            'loss': 1,
            'points': 4,
            'wins': 1},
 'rank_6': {'team': 'Randomteam3',
            'draw': 2,
            'games': 3,
            'loss': 2,
            'points': 2,
            'wins': 0}}
```

Comment: If you zip the point list first, you don't even need the key.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, True but I was going to use a dict straight away so had the team first .

Answer (score 1):

You can sort your list and get the elements with a simple slice :

```
>>> sorted(team_info,key=itemgetter(0),reverse=True)[:4]
[[12, 3, 0, 0, 3], [10, 3, 0, 0, 6], [9, 0, 2, 2, 3], [7, 2, 1, 1, 3]]

>>> sorted(team_info,key=itemgetter(0),reverse=True)[-2:]
[[4, 1, 1, 1, 3], [2, 0, 2, 2, 3]]
```

And if you want the name of teams too you can use `zip` :

```
>>> sorted(zip(teams,team_info),key=itemgetter(1,0),reverse=True)[:4]
[('Randomteam4', [12, 3, 0, 0, 3]), ('Randomteam6', [10, 3, 0, 0, 6]), ('Randomteam5', [9, 0, 2, 2, 3]), ('Randomteam1', [7, 2, 1, 1, 3])]
>>> 
>>> zip(*sorted(zip(teams,team_info),key=itemgetter(1,0),reverse=True)[:4])[0]
('Randomteam4', 'Randomteam6', 'Randomteam5', 'Randomteam1')
```

You can also use `heapq.nlargest` and `nsmallest` to get the N largest and smallest elements :

```
>>> import heapq
>>> heapq.nlargest(4,team_info,key=itemgetter(0))
[[12, 3, 0, 0, 3], [10, 3, 0, 0, 6], [9, 0, 2, 2, 3], [7, 2, 1, 1, 3]]

>>> heapq.nsmallest(2,team_info,key=itemgetter(0))
[[2, 0, 2, 2, 3], [4, 1, 1, 1, 3]]
```

Comment: I get Error with `key = itemgetter`